# How to get all non matching rows from both tables in one query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with similar columns and I would like to know the difference between these tables. So if all values (column-wise) of the row exists in both table it is fine (I do not want to see this), while I want to see all rows that.

I have tried this:

```
select m.*, t.*
from  test.test1 m 
full outer join test.test2 t 
    on row(m) = row(t)

where m.date = '2022-11-01'
```

but I am getting all rows only from the first table. Note. I want only one query (no subqueries)

Comment: Unioning two anti-joins should do the trick, but it's not clear [to me] what the output should look like. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Your where condition can't match NULL rows from m, so all the rows in t unmatched to m can't be returned.

Comment: Note that `row(m) = row(t)` can be simplified to `m = t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the null check for your key columns in the where statement:

```
select m.*, t.*
from  test.test1 m 
full outer join test.test2 t 
    on row(m) = row(t)
where m.KEY is null or t.KEY is null and m.date = '2022-11-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EXCEPT/EXCEPT ALL set operators to compare tables with the column layout (data-types and order of columns (if using SELECT *) must match).

```
SELECT 'IN TEST1 but not in TEST2' as SRC, EA.*
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM test.test1 m
  where m.date='2022-11-01'
  EXCEPT ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM test.test2
  ) EA
union all
SELECT 'IN TEST2 but not in TEST1' as SRC, EA.*
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM test.test2
  EXCEPT ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM test.test1 m
  where m.date='2022-11-01'
  ) EA
```